# How to describe belongs to many?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have three model classes User, Product and Purchase. Purchase describes quantity of a product for ordering. So a purchase has one product, and a product may belongs to many purchases. But Mongoid messages about problem:

```
Mongoid::Errors::InverseNotFound (
Problem:
  When adding a(n) Product to Purchase#product, Mongoid could not determine the inverse foreign key to set. The attempted key was 'purchase_id'.
Summary:
  When adding a document to a relation, Mongoid attempts to link the newly added document to the base of the relation in memory, as well as set the foreign key to link them on the database side. In this case Mongoid could not determine what the inverse foreign key was.
Resolution:
  If an inverse is not required, like a belongs_to or has_and_belongs_to_many, ensure that :inverse_of => nil is set on the relation. If the inverse is needed, most likely the inverse cannot be figured out from the names of the relations and you will need to explicitly tell Mongoid on the relation what the inverse is.

 Example:
   class Lush
     include Mongoid::Document
     has_one :whiskey, class_name: "Drink", inverse_of: :alcoholic
   end

   class Drink
     include Mongoid::Document
     belongs_to :alcoholic, class_name: "Lush", inverse_of: :whiskey
   end):
```

But the mongoid's example doesn't cover my case, because I have "belongs to many" relation.

This is my models:

```
class Purchase
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :quantity, text: String
  has_one :product
  belongs_to :user
end

class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :purchases
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :purchases
end
```

How to describe the relations properly?

Comment: I would suggest writing that a product `has_many` purchases and a purchase `belongs_to` a product. Otherwise you'll end up with a single purchase per product. Also, look out for the typo under Purchase: `belongs_to :user`

Comment: @mdepolli Thanks for note about the typo. Of course, it will work. But I think this solution does not describe relation semantics enough clearly.

Answer (score 1):

@Ajcodez is right that your relations were backwards. However, if you were actually looking for a belongs_to_many relation (a HABTM which only stores ids on one side of the relationship), that can be implemented via:

`has_and_belongs_to_many :name, inverse_of: nil`

see: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2473

Comment: if you want to name the relation something other than the model name: `has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: nil`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the relation backwards. You need each `Purchase` document to contain the ID of a product, which means `Purchase` belongs to a product. And the `Product` therefore has many purchases.

Remember every time you write `belongs_to`, the ID of the parent goes into the document. You can't really `belong_to <plural>`.